# How to use MathJax in a svelte project?

Tags: svelte, mathjax

I am working on a svelte text editor project in svelte , the code is very simple ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6b1585a60c8248a78248d820a37093c2?version=3.32.3)) :

```html
<script>
    let rawText
    let formatText = (text)=>{
        // Text Formating
        return text
    }
    $: formatedText = formatText(rawText)
</script>

<textarea bind:value={rawText}></textarea>
{#if formatedText}
    {formatedText}
{/if}
```

I need to be able to write math equations.

To do so I have found MathJax but I can't find a clean way to import it into my svelte app

I have tried  multiples approach like

### the npm way :

using :

```
npm i mathjax
```

and on the svelte component :

```js
import MathJax from 'mathjax'
```

But when I do this the app turn white without any error

### The svelte:head way :

The second solution I tried was to import MathJax from a cdn in a script tag like that :

```html
<svelte:head>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script
        id="MathJax-script"
        async
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

And it kinda works because I can access MathJax functions in the browser console but I don't know to use them in my svelte app

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWa1Z.png)

### The hacky way :

The last solution I have found [in this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ebd12dbf04574b2bb40003cc8a4299b0?version=3.14.1) leads to the same problem.

So my question is how to import mathjax in my svelte project or can I use something else?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<tex-chtml />` to your `App.svelte` component?

Comment: No, where do I need to write this? I have found this [example](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web/blob/master/tex-chtml.html.md) on the doc but can't figure out how it works

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you finally used the example in your comment. I hope you did.

For anyone else wanting a solution for this, I tried the following. (I don't know if it is correct for a Svelte application, but it worked, at least)

The example found in the comment [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web/blob/master/tex-chtml.html.md) says as follows:

```
// Thanks to https://github.com/dpvc
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]}
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

So in my `app/public/index.html` file, I added the script pointing to the CDN, just as it says in the comment.

After that, I tried using the Latex notation directly on the Svelte script, as:

```
# Svelte file
<script lang="ts">
  let equ = `$$x = \\frac{t}{3}$$`;
</script>
<main>
  {equ}
</main>
```

And it did work.

At first, it wasn't working, so with my monke brain, I thought maybe it was because I didn't add the other script part to the `index.html` file. I added it and it worked. So maybe it was because the language server was not working or something else... I don't know for sure, I am using VSCode and after a restart and deleting that part, I worked. So that is my super investigation about it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Luis' answer, if you see that Mathjax is flaky, add this to your page component.

```
afterNavigate(() => MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]));
```

This will rerender Mathjax on navigation to the page.